# 2 Forms on the page with JS validation - one throws email validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I've added 2 forms on one page of a wordpress website: one for mobile display and one in the sidebar for desktop computers (bigger screens).

I've done this previously and can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work this time.

What happens now is that the desktop form always throws a validation error on the email field, even when entering a valid email. It **only** doesn't work for the email field on the desktop form, the validation works on all other input fields (name, ..) - and on the mobile form as well.

I'm using simple Java Script to validate the forms, both forms use the same function for validating the email address.
the Form validation is triggered by the submit button and all form fields have different id's.

If I'm **not** displaying the mobile form, the desktop email validation works fine?!?

Now to the code (just the key elements for this question):
**html-form on the page**

```
 <form class="formMob">
    <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fullName-mob" name="fullName" type="text">       
    <div class="form-error" id="error-fullName-mob">
            <span>Please enter your full name</span>
    </div>

    <label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email-mob" name="email" placeholder="email address">
    <div class="form-error" id="error-email-mob">
            <span>Please enter a valid email</span>
    </div>

    <button class="submitMe" id="submitForm-mob">Submit Details</button>
</form>

 <!-- Desktop form -->
 <form class="form">
        <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" type="text">       
    <div class="form-error" id="error-fullName">
            <span>Please enter your full name</span>
    </div>

    <label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email address">
    <div class="form-error" id="error-email">
            <span>Please enter a valid email</span>
    </div>
    <button class="submitMe" id="submitForm">Submit Details</button>
</form>
```

**The Java Script:**

```
$jq(function(){
    $jq('#submitForm').click(function(event) {
        /*validate email*/
        if(validateEmail( $jq('#email').val() )){
            $jq('#error-email').hide(); 
        }
        else{
            valido = false;
            $jq('#error-email').show('fast');
        }
    });

    $jq('#submitForm-mob').click(function(event) {
        /*validate email*/
        if(validateEmail($jq('#email-mob').val())){
            $jq('#error-email-mob').hide(); 
        }
        else{
           valido = false;
           $jq('#error-email-mob').show('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Would appreciate any comments or ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem.

I missed to see that on these wordpress pages where it doesn't work **comments are activated** as well.
The comments have an input form with an email field also which is **has the same ID** for the email field and appears first in the code.

So JavaScript checked the comment email field (when there are 2 fields with the same ID Javascript uses the first one that appears in the code) for validation.

Now I simply had to use a different ID for the desktop form, like so:

```
<input type="email" id="email-reg" name="email" placeholder="email address">
```

And adapt the JS validation accordingly...

```
if(validateEmail( $jq('#email-reg').val() )){
        $jq('#error-email-reg').hide(); 
    }
    else{
        valido = false;
        $jq('#error-email-reg').show('fast');
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

one issue is that your labels for your mob version are pointing to the Id's of the inputs for the full version

```
<label for="email">E-mail Address</label>
```

should be

```
<label for="email-mob">E-mail Address</label>
```

Probably not the cause of validation errors, but would cause issues for screen readers

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm on my way to fix that. I was of the opinion that the 'for' attribute of the label points to the 'name' of the input field.
and you are also right: this is not causing the issue - I made that mistake also with the other fields where the validation is working.

Comment: noprobs - AFIK - the for attribute points to the id of the input not the name - but I could be wrong. :))

Comment: Just checked up on it ;) you're right it points to the ID. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp